# Team City - Agent install question

Tags: teamcity

What does it mean to have TeamCity build agent installed on another machine than the Build server? The way I understand is that I need "TeamCity server install" to start a "agent install" right? Right now I have TeamCity build server installed with webUI and all of that on a windows server machine. Now what do I need to do, to install an agent on another machine (another server machine?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The teamcity documentation is really good. Check out the [Installing Agents](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Setting+up+and+Running+Additional+Build+Agents) section.

You can have a build agent on the same machine as the server or install agents on other machines. I would use another machine for the agent if you are going to have multiple agents or a really heavy workload on an agent.

From the machine you want to install the agent on open up a web browser and point it at your team city web ui. Click the agents tab. In the upper right should be a link called "install build agents". Click it and choose your install method of choice.

Comment: You said - "From the machine you want to install the agent on open up a web browser ....." so I need to install TeamCity software on this machine first right? does that mean I am installing TeamCity build server softwre on the agent machine as well?

Comment: @ZVenue. No you don't need to install the server in two places. Lets say you installed the server on machine A and want an agent on machine B. Go to B, open a browser. Browse to the server's ui on A. Click the agent's tab, click install build agents and then pick the right installer for you. That will download the agent installer to machine B and then you can run it there.

Comment: I did just that, but I still see the default agent I was working with on the server. I dont see the new agent that I just installed on machine B. I can see the new Build Agent I installed running in the windows services (control panel). But its not visible in the UI (as u said, I logged into machine A teamcity UI from a browser in Machine B)

Comment: @ZVenue - when you click on the agents tab in the server ui it should show more tabs labeled "Connected()", "Disconnected()", "Unauthorized()"  with numbers in the parentheses. What are the numbers in your case?

Comment: 1-0-0 .. the only agent I see is in the connected tab and it is the original one I was working with .. that was installed by default on the server (A)... does not show me the two new agents I installed on machine B.

Comment: @ZVenue Go to the directory where you installed the agent on machine B. Open the conf directory. Open the buildAgent.properties file. Make sure the `serverUrl` property is set to the url of your build server. You may need to restart the agent service after saving the buildAgent.properties file.

Comment: Server URL is correct. The issue was with windows interactive services. Found out that I have to disable this interactive service by reading error logs in the server manager section. I did just that and the agent started showing up immediately in the web UI. May be you could explain why this worked... I haven't investigated this further. For now though issue seems to be resolved. Thank you very much for much insight.

Answer (score 2):

@ZVenue: The way I have TeamCity configured is: 1 TC Server (windows) and build agents on 3 Unix boxes (running separate kinds of builds). This gives me a central build console for all activities.

Hope this helps!