# Installing TeamCity remote agents is not working

Tags: teamcity

I already have TeamCity server and one default agent on the server machine A. I am trying to install a remote build agent on another machine B . These are the steps I took:
1. In a browser in B, went to TeamCity UI (that is on A)
2. Clicked on "Install Build Agents" link
3. Went through all the steps of install.. for server url I gave http://teamcityservername and changed the port to unique number.
4. I see build agent folders created on machine B

But I dont see the remote agent I installed just now, in the "Agents" tab in the teamcity UI. I tried to add a new agent. Even this created a new folder in B for this new agent, but still no sight of the two new agents I added in UI. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds are that either the build agent process is failing to start, or the agent is unable to connect to the TC server for some reason.

Ideas for things to check:

- Firstly, is the build agent service actually running on machine B?
- If the build agent service is failing to start correctly, are there any errors in the system log relating to the service? Does the build agent run correctly when run manually from a command line?
- Is the build agent running with appropriate user permissions?
- Check the logs directory inside the build agent's installation directory. Are there any errors appearing in the log files that point to possible solutions?
- If all else fails, double check the build agent configuration - server name, port etc. Typing errors happen to the best of us! :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are right. I actually posted the resolution last night here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418100/team-city-agent-install-question.. it is regarding Windows Interactive service disabling. got there by checking the logs